# Javascript Error: RerenceError: LoadObject is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am getting an error

```
RerenceError: LoadObject is not defined
```

While retrieving some data using JavaScript and AJAX it stucks near

```
} else {
   var request=LoadObject;
```

my code is:

```
function advdetails1(param,spntag){
 if(document.authcfrm.y.value!="add"){
  var madvcd=param.value;
  if(madvcd==""){
   alert('Enter proper Advocate Code!');
   param.focus();
   return;
  } else {
   var request=LoadObject();
   var mside=document.authcfrm.m_sideflg.value;
   request.open("GET","ajaxfunction.php?gadvcd="+madvcd+"&flag=ADV1&side="+mside,true);
   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState == 1) {
    }
    if(request.readyState == 4) {
     response = request.responseText;
     response = response.trim();
     arrresponse=response.split('~');
     document.getElementById(spntag).value=arrresponse[0];
     document.getElementById(spntag+'_adv_email').value=arrresponse[1];
     document.getElementById(spntag+'_adv_telno').value=arrresponse[2];
     document.getElementById(spntag+'_adv_mobileno').value=arrresponse[3];
     document.getElementById(spntag+'_advc').value=arrresponse[4];

//  alert(document.getElementById(spntag+'_advc').value);

    if(document.getElementById(spntag+'_adv_email').value!=''){
        document.getElementById(spntag+'_adv_na_email').checked='';
    }else{document.getElementById(spntag+'_adv_na_email').checked='checked';}

    if(document.getElementById(spntag+'_adv_telno').value!=''){
        document.getElementById(spntag+'_na_adv_telno').checked='';
    }else{document.getElementById(spntag+'_na_adv_telno').checked='checked';}

    if(document.getElementById(spntag+'_adv_mobileno').value!=''){
        document.getElementById(spntag+'_na_adv_mobileno').checked='';
    }else{document.getElementById(spntag+'_na_adv_mobileno').checked='checked';}

    if(document.getElementById(spntag+'_advc').value!=''){
        document.getElementById(spntag+'_na_advc').checked='';
    }else{document.getElementById(spntag+'_na_advc').checked='checked';}
    }
   }
   request.send(null);
  }
 }
}
```

This code is not working after the line

```
var request=LoadObject();
```

I have to get some data from database after matching a field in the table and get all relevant data and put that data in relevant fields on the form.
Please help to sort out this problem.

Comment: You probably forgot to copy LoadObject definition. I presume it loads XMLHttpRequest object--to save lines.

Comment: @Cody `LoadObject()` might not be in the desired scope.

Comment: But this same code is working on other pages, without any changes. I also recheck all that pages over and over again but didn't find any code where LoadObject is defined. Is there any other alternative to do the same thing?